# How to hold the two input value params at onetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two input tags. One is `select_tag` and `checkbox_tag`.

Select box is to select the customer name and when one is selected, the other checkbox will display with the click event.

If I select a customer only without selecting a customer, then searched. It hold the customer name select params after the search.

But when I select customer name and checked the Decendents tag both, the search will not hold the both params. After the search both params are gone. I need to hold the params after the search.

This is my view:

```
  .row
    .col-md-3
      = label_tag "Customer/Supplier Name"
      = select_tag "search_customer_supplier[id]", options_from_collection_for_select(Organization.customers_and_suppliers, :id, :name, params.dig('search_customer_supplier', 'id')), class: "form-control parent_class chosen-select", id: "search_registered_customers", include_blank: true
    .col-md-10.small_scale_margin-top2#check_children_wrapper.hide
      = label_tag "Descendent"
      = check_box_tag "organization_children", false
```

This is my controller:

```rb
  if params[:search].present? or params[:excel_report].present?

    search_customer_supplier = params[:search_customer_supplier]

    if params[:organization_children].present? and search_customer_supplier["id"].present?
      organization_id = search_customer_supplier["id"]
      organization = Organization.find(organization_id)
      anchestor_ids = organization.anchestors.map{|o| o[:member].id }
      search_customer_supplier["id"] = "(#{anchestor_ids.join(' OR ')})" if anchestor_ids.any?
    end
```

Comment: Not really sure what you mean "hold the params". Are they not all being sent to the server?

Comment: @max pleaner
when i clicked on search button.It will display the search results according to the customer name.when clicked search buttonI , selected customer goes.Becuase of the  page refresh.I need to print excel report according to the result.My problem is i need to hold the selected customer name after the refresh of page to print the same data.

Comment: In whatever action you're handling this form submission, couldn't you define an instance variable with the customer name and then reference that variable in your view?

Comment: @AnujaDx have you read about [session/flash](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session)?